# How to programmatically check if a TFS 2013's backup is running?

Tags: tfs

for maintenance purpose, I used to implement a "graceful reboot" script for TFS 2010. Such a reboot was required to give opportunity for a server to install patches. But we might not reboot a server while "builds" or "Backups" were currently running.

So, I did a script to disable all TFS Services (Source Control, Build, backup plan) and wait for completion of all builds and backup tasks currently running, before rebooting the TFS servers.

To wait on "backup tasks" completion, I was programmatically monitoring the Windows Scheduled Tasks created by TFS Power Tools 2010: TfsDeleteOldBackup TfsDifferentialBackup TfsFullBackup TfsTransactionalBackup.

Since we have migrated to TFS 2013, there are no such Windows Scheduled Tasks anymore created by the "Backup Plan Wizard"... So, I wonder how I can check now, with TFS 2013, that there is no backup task currently running and disable them programmatically ?!

Any idea ? I don't see where those tasks are defined and executed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backup jobs have been re-implemented as TFS agent jobs since TFS 2012.
You can access the information you want through the tfs client object model:

```
var tfsConfigServerUri = new Uri(String.Format("http://localhost:8080/tfs"));
var tfsConfigServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsConfigServerUri);
var jobService = tfsConfigServer.GetService<ITeamFoundationJobService>();
foreach(var job in jobService.QueryJobs())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am only giving it a try now... Unfortunately, there is no obvious method/query to know if a job instance is currently running. QueryJobs() returns info about job Definition.. Not about currently running job instances. Also, QueryJobsHistory() returns info only for jobs already completed. But tt should definitively by possible as I see a method StopJob that can stop a Job "In-Progress" (as per MSDN). So there is at least some internals to get job instances. I will try to look at methods related to the "Job Agents"

Comment: I found that "A given job has one of five states: In progress (Running, Paused, Stopping, …), queued, scheduled for future execution, host-blocked or not scheduled" [Chris Sidi's blog]. This kind of info is however only available when using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobService instead of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamFoundationJobService.